# Generating empty log files with Log4J2

Tags: logging, log4j2

I have had a look at the existing questions on the matter, but still I could not solve the issue. This is my POM with all the log4j2 dependencies:

```
<dependencyManagement>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My `log4j2.properties` file is structured as follows:

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=target/myLog.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
```

Finally, I created the logger in my test class as follows:

```
private Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(TestClass.class.getName());
```

While I can output all the logs to the console, I am only returned with an empty file under /target (as specified).

Can you help? Do you see anything fundamentally wrong in my properties file?

Thank you,

I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have managed to output the logs to the file and to the console:

```
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = file
appender.file.fileName=target/myLog.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=%d [%-15.15t] %-5p %-30.30c{1} - %m%n

appender.out.type = Console
appender.out.name = out
appender.out.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.out.layout.pattern = %d [%-15.15t] %-5p %-30.30c{1} - %m%n
rootLogger.level = all
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref = file
rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref = out
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the exact problem mentioned here, resolved when I corrected package name in `logger.file.name` key of `log4j2.properties`.

Example:

```
logger.file.name=com.amazon.resources
```

Answer (score 0):

An empty log file is a sign that something is wrong in the configuration file.  In my case, I had an invalid log level.  For instance, I had :

```
<Loggers>
    <Root level="fine">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Root>
```

But `fine` isn't a valid standard level and it worked when I changed it to `info`. As stated by the [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html), log levels should be one of those :

- OFF
- FATAL
- ERROR
- WARN
- INFO
- DEBUG
- TRACE
- ALL